# Jcrop not working properly on modal window

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I have a wrapper div `box` that is the modal window. There is an image inside the modal window. When Jcrop() is added to this image, I get an unintended result. As shown below:

[image]

[image]

Notice that the image appears inside the modal window and outside. This is the jQuery code used:

```
$("#previewSub").Jcrop();  //previewSub is the smaller preview
```

How can I get around this issue? I tried removing the Jcrop from the picture when the modal is closed but I still get the same result.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/d562yrsp/1/

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or snippet, difficult to help without an example

Comment: @DelightedD0D sure but I don't know how to include the plugin in the fiddle

Comment: You can find a CDN version of the required files online [like here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-jcrop) then add them to the fiddle using the "External Resources" tab as shown in [this image](http://prntscr.com/9joatc) But, [Here is a fiddle with the files added](https://jsfiddle.net/d562yrsp/), just add your code to it

Comment: @DelightedD0D so heres a fiddle that demonstrates my problem https://jsfiddle.net/d562yrsp/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the effect you want, change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="modal">
  <div class="preview-container">
    <img id="previewSub" src="http://www.cuteadorable.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/cuteadorable-kitty.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<button id="abutton">
  show modal
</button>
```

Change your CSS to this:

```
#modal {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}
.preview-container {
  top: 100px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #2185C5;
  position: relative;
}
#previewSub {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;/* use auto here so it doesnt distort the aspect ratio of the image */
}
#abutton {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 350px;
}
```

And change your jQuery to this:

```
$('#abutton').on("click", function() {
  $("#modal").show();
  $('#previewSub').Jcrop();
});
```

#### [Here is an updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d562yrsp/3/)

Note that Jcrop sets the below styling in the target image:

`style="display: block; visibility: visible; width: 150px; height: 84px; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;"`

This overrides the `position`, `top`, and `left` settings your were adding in the rule for `#previewSub`. To avoid this, I have placed the image in a container div with the class `preview-container` and applied the positioning to that container instead.

The CSS may need some tweaking for your needs but this should get you sorted.